# Storing a Timestamp as a Binary Fraction in C

Tags: c, time, binary

I'm working on an implementation of an obscure network protocol, and one of the requirements is that each packet header should contain a 56-bit timestamp, with the first 4 bytes containing an integer number of seconds since the epoch, and the remaining 3 bytes used to contain a binary fraction of the current second. In other words, the last 3 bytes should represent the number of 2^-24 seconds since the previous second. The first part of the timestamp is trivial, but I'm struggling to implement the C code that would store the fractional part of the timestamp. Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

For completeness' sake, here's the timestamp code I have so far. `primaryHeader` is a `char*` that I'm using to store the header data for the packet. You can assume that the first 6 bytes in `primaryHeader` contain valid, unrelated data, and that `primaryHeader` is large enough to contain everything that needs to be stored in it.

```
int secs = (int)time(NULL);
memcpy(&primaryHeader[7], &secs, sizeof(int));
// TODO: Compute fractional portion of the timestamp and memcpy to primaryHeader[11]
```

Comment: Note that memcpy() assumes that the first four bytes of your header and your local machine's integer have the same endianness. Not knowing the protocol, I can't say for sure, but most network protocols are big-endian and most machines are little-endian, so that may be an issue. And you don't tell us which way the last three bytes are either.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to keep the question as short and to-the-point as possible. I'm prepared to deal with the endianness issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `time()` function will only give you seconds. You a higher resolution timer.

```
struct timespec t;
timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
int secs = t.tv_sec; // Whole seconds
int frac = ((int64_t)t.tv_nsec << 24) / 1000000000; // Fractional part.
```

If this is not available you can use `clock_gettime`, but `clock_gettime` is not found on Windows.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You appear to think that this doesn’t answer the question. Could you explain the discrepancy?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think you may be reading the question differently from how I read the question. If that’s the case, ask for clarification from the OP, I can only speak to my own understanding of the question. And I don’t think I’m just fixating on a bug.

Comment: Refresh your page.

Comment: What about `timespec_get` then? It's in C11 but despite that it seems to exist on windows

Comment: @harold: Thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: @harold My search of  `timespec_get()`on C11 failed to find it.  Please provide citation of its C11 existence.  Hmm I do see it in C17: 7.27.2.5 The timespec_get function.  Perhaps my C11 is "drafty"?

Comment: @chux Perhaps that's the one normative change in C17... I always wondered what that was. (I don't see it either, using N1548)

Comment: @chux https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get lists it as "since C11", could be that they're wrong

Comment: I found a number of citations that claim it’s in the C11 standard. In glibc, it appears to be guarded by `__USE_ISO_C11`.

Comment: Dietrich Epp  thanks about `timespec_get().  Re: "clock_gettime is not found on Windows." --> its more of a compiler issue than an OS issue.

Comment: C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):
7.27.2.5 The timespec_get function (p: 390)

Comment: @JL2210 Yes it is in C11 [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the latest C11 draft), but not N1548.

Comment: Note: `int secs = t.tv_sec;` OK until [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  Perhaps `unsigned secs = t.tv_sec;` if `time_t` is 64-bit to carry OP through to 2108